# usage of infinitive after feel

Tags: word-usage, verb-agreement, infinitives

What is grammatically wrong with the sentence,  "I feel to eat."?  After the verb feel, can the infinitive of another verb be used?

Comment: I would recommend to use "feel like to do" instead of "feel to do".

Answer (score 2):

Infinitives are not usually used after the verb *to feel.*  To express desire, the usual construction is *I feel like + gerund,* which is to say *I feel like eating.*

If, however, you prefer to use an infinitive, then change the finite verb: e.g. *I want to eat, I wish to eat, I hope to eat* are all correct, but never **I feel to eat.*